# Should education times include "leave of absences"?

Tags: united-states, university

I enrolled in a grad school for two semesters (Fall 2019 and Spring 2020). Because of the Pandemic, I could not continue my studies. I took a "leave of absence" for the next two semesters (Fall 2020 and Spring 2021) hoping that I will be able to continue afterwards. After Spring 2021, I decided not to continue.

I am applying for a position where I need to provide accurate dates for all my previous education. For the time I studied in grad school, does the "leave of absence" count? I.e should I put my education dates from fall 2019 to spring 2021 (which includes two semesters of excused absences)? Or, should I put fall 2019 to spring 2020? The transcript shows two semesters of coursework and two semesters of leave of absence.

Comment: We cannot answer this question here, without knowing in which country you apply. This is country-specific. Otherwise, you may ask your social affairs institution if any, or consult the jurisdiction of your country.

Comment: this is for the United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not return, it would be odd and raise more questions to list your education as going a year past when you stopped working on it.